# ORA-39165: Schema 'name of schema'; was not found

Tags: oracle, database-administration

## **ORA-39165: Schema "epehchan"; was not found.**

I have created table tablespace by using this command:-

`create tablespace epehchan datafile 'C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata\XE\epehchan' size 1M autoectend on;`

Also created the user by using this command:-

`create user epehchan identified by epehchan123 default table space epehchan temporary tablespace temp;`

and gave all privileges to epehchan.

Now I have the EPEHCHAN.DMP file in "D:\param_bkp\bkp" and created the directory "dump_dir" in that folder. Also grant privileges by following commands:-

`GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY dump_dir TO epehchan;`

`GRANT IMP_FULL_DATABASE TO epehchan;`

I am using the import command to import the dump file:-

`impdp epehchan/epehchan123 dumpfile=EPEHCHAN.DMP directory=dump_dir schemas=epehchan;`

while executing I got this error

```
> Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Thu Oct 19 11:31:20 2023
> 
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
> 
> Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
> ORA-39002: invalid operation
> ORA-39165: Schema epehchan; was not found.
```

How do I import EPEHCHAN.dmp file properly.

Comment: Remove the semicolon from the end of the impdp command? From the error that is being treated as part of the schema name.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole. It is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the semicolon from the end of the impdp command cuz it is being treated as part of the schema name.